# BC math string into scientific notation

Tags: php

i use bc math (http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).
the value is, e.g.,

```
$value = "0.0000000000000000000001111111111111111111112";
```

how can i transform it into scientific notation. it should be like this:

```
$value = "1.111111111111111111112E-22";
```

i tried amongst others

```
sprintf("%E",$value) or a (float)
```

but the result are only

```
1.111111E-22 (sprintf)
```

That are not so many significant figures as it should be :(

Comment: Apart from PHPs double not retaining more than ~15 significant digits, you are probably asking about the precision by `printf` being cut down. Use `printf("%.16E",$value);` to get a slightly longer scientific number.

Comment: hi mario, tnx

1.1111111111111111E-22 //with 16
1.11111111111111106062E-22 //with 20

but not exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count how many zeroes there are.

Note that because you are using big numbers, you have to work on them as strings. So...

```
if( preg_match("/^0\.0*/",$value,$m)) {
    $zeroes = strlen($m[0]);
    $value = substr($value,$zeroes,1)
                .rtrim(".".substr($value,$zeroes+1),"0.")
                ."E-".($zeroes-1);
}
elseif( preg_match("/(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?/",$value,$m)) {
    $zeroes = strlen($m[1]);
    $value = substr($value,0,1)
                .rtrim(".".substr($m[1],1).$m[2],"0.")
                ."E+".($zeroes-1);
}
// else 1 <= number < 10, so no transformation needed
```

Test cases:

- 1000000 => 1E+6
- 1234.5678 => 1.2345678E+3
- 0.9 => 9E-1
- 0.123 => 1.23E-1
- 0.00000011111122222 => 1.1111122222E-7

Comment: tnx niet :) for - i think - the best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do `$float_value = (float)$value;` and get `1.1111111111111E-22` but beyond that the `float` cannot offer more precision so it can't show that `2` at the end.

Comment: tnx mike, but as i said "a (float)" has too less significant figures

Comment: sure it worked - but not exactly - and my "a (float)" was before your  answer (because it was already in my first version of my question :-P - i only corrected "sprint" to "sprintf" ;) nevertheless - tnx :)